# High CPU usage while using poll system call to wait on fds

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have this unique problem where the poll system call of linux used in my code gets the fds it waits on polled in , i mean POLLIN every millisecond. This is causing high CPU usage . I have supplied a timeout of 100 milliseconds and it seems to be of no use. Can any one suggest an alternative.

```
    for (;;) {

 ACE_Time_Value doWork(0, 20000);  
 ACE_OS::sleep(doWork);  ----------------------------> Causing low throughput, put to decrease CPU usage / On removing this we see high CPU , but throughput is achieved.
..
.
..
 if ((exitCode = fxDoWork()) < 0) {
  break;}

}

fxDoWork()
{
ACE_Time_Value selectTime;
selectTime.set(0, 100000);
..
..
..
ACE_INT32 waitResult = ACE_OS::poll(myPollfds, eventCount, &selectTime);-----------------------------> Pollin happens for every milli second/Timeout is not at all useful
..
..
..
}
===============================================================
```

Comment: What kind of fd are you polling, sockets, fifo, pipe, files?

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: @Tiran they are socket fds

Comment: Is the return value from poll actually an error?  This would mean it's not waiting, so your code just loops.

Comment: I have serious throughput issues because of the CPU usage. I have deliberately put some sleep to reduce CPU but now it is decreasing the response time.

Comment: @Neil No I have not added the complete code as it is too huge, it has all conditions checked , but i get a POLLIN every One millisecond with out the ACE_OS::sleep(doWork)

Comment: If you change it to have a 1 second poll wait time, and it is still high CPU, does that mean it's not the polling that's the problem, it's that you have lots of packets to process?  After the poll, how are you reading the socket and processing the data?

Comment: @Neil I am using a multi threaded environment where this is the manager and worker does the processing part.

Comment: Are you sure it is the polling thread that is the high usage and not the processing threads?  Are the processing threads already created but sleeping, or are you creating a new thread each time a packet comes in?

Comment: @samairtimer if you mean there are data to be processed almost every millisecond, then I think high CPU usage is the way it is because poll() returns whenever there is data OR timeout happens.

Comment: If you're getting a POLLIN every millisecond, then fiddling around with poll is likely the wrong thing to do. If there's data available every miliseconds, then sleep()'ing or having a longer timeout is not going to help - the data is still there and needs to be processed. Try to figure out _where_ your code spends CPU time. Just make sure you read the data, and handle the scenario when reading errors or indicates the socket is disconnected - you don't want to put a finised or bad socket back to be poll'ed as that will just generate a new instant event.

Comment: @nos Is there a case that using epoll will help, more over the same piece of code in windows using WitForMultipleObjects did not cause any such CPU usage pattern.

Comment: @samairtimer If you have thousands of concurrent connections, epoll will probably help, if you're just having a couple of connections up to a few hundred, it's not going to help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to accumulate enough data OR a specific timeout happens to reduce CPU usage, right?  If that's the case, you can use recvmmsg(): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html

> The recvmmsg() system call is an extension of recvmsg(2) that allows
>          the caller to receive multiple messages from a socket using a single
>          system call.  (This has performance benefits for some applications.)
>          A further extension over recvmsg(2) is support for a timeout on the
>          receive operation.

Comment: When you post a link, try to quote part of the webpage so even if the link gets broken, your answer is still useful for futur users